# Rails: can you change asset_host in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to test my AWS S3 bucket, as a host for my assets, but when I change `config.action_controller.asset_host` in my `development.rb` file in my config/environments/ folder, the image that is currently in the S3 bucket under `my.png` is not accessible via an `image_tag('my.png')`. 
I am wondering if this practice simply does not work for development as usually there is no reason to host local assets on a seperate server...

Comment: What is the output of the image_tag call? What do you expect it to be? Did you restart your development server after making that change?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom it is rendering `"http://fls-net.s3.amazonaws.com/images/01_upscale.jpg"`.

Comment: where `fls-net` is the name of my buckect and images is a folder immediately in the top level of the bucket. How can I tell if it is a permissions / config issue?

Comment: Request the file via curl.  It's an access/permission problem. https://gist.github.com/phallstrom/4fabd7c5c91e405d4bfd